# EOSIO unsupported key_type uint64_t

Tags: eosjs, multi-index, javascript

I am using a secondary key to get table rows:

```
static async getItemById(itemId){
    try{
      const rpc = new JsonRpc(process.env.REACT_APP_EOS_HTTP_ENDPOINT);
      const result = await rpc.get_table_rows({
        "json": true,
        "code": process.env.REACT_APP_EOS_CONTRACT_NAME,
        "scope": process.env.REACT_APP_EOS_CONTRACT_NAME,
        "index_position": "secondary",
        "key_type": "uint64_t",
        "table": "items",
        "limit": 10,
        "lower_bound": itemId,
      });
      console.log(result.rows)
      return result.rows;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Unsupported secondary index type: uint64_t
    at new RpcError (eosjs-rpcerror.js:27)
    at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:121)
    at step (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:37)
    at Object.next (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:18)
    at fulfilled (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to use `i64` instead of `uint64_t`. The [API reference](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.0/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index/?query=tertiary&page=1#operation/get_table_rows) is confusing. It clearly mentions `uint64_t` as an example for the `key_type`!